# Linq to SQL - SQL join statement with specific return

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following table entity with my sql-database :

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

[Table(Name = "Users")]
class Users
{
    [Column(Name="UserKey", IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public string UserKey { get; set; }
    [Column(Name="Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IList<T_UsersRoles> Roles = new List<UsersRoles>();
}

[Table(Name ="Roles")]
class UsersRoles
{
    [Column(Name="UserKey", IsPrimaryKey =true)]
    public string UserKey { get; set; }
    [Column(Name ="RoleKey", IsPrimaryKey =true)]
    public string RoleKey { get; set; }
}
```

the only member which is not part of my database is the `public IList<T_UsersRoles> Roles = new List<UsersRoles>();` in `class Users`

I now want **just a single SQL-Transaction** and have a filled `class Users` object with a filled list of all roles the user has.

How is this possible?

I already made a join select on both table with an anonymous object `new {user, role}` but that is not what i want to get back

And i already made this. But here are too many sql-transactions (amount of user +1)

````
var users = from user in dataContext.GetTable<Users>()               
                where user.Id == "1234" | user.Id == "5678"
                select user;

foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.Roles = (from roles in dataContext.GetTable<UsersRoles>() where roles.Id == user.Id select roles).ToList<UsersRoles>();
    
    Console.WriteLine(user.Id + " " + user.UserName + ":");
    foreach (var role in user.Roles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- " + role.RoleKey);
    }
}```
````

Comment: I think you can fill the `Roles` list in the select statement. I think it would be easier if you included the code wiht `join` in you question. If you scaffolded your model from the database and have foreign keys betwen Users and Roles set up you would get much of the needed code for free.

Comment: does var data = Users.Include(x => x.Roles).ToList() not give what you want?

Comment: IQueryable<Users> does not include a definition for the Include()-Method. And i also would like to have the IList<Roles>-Member filled

Comment: See the duplicate. You have to use `DataLoadOptions`. Ignore all this talk about `Include` in the question and answer. `Include` is an Entity-Framework method.